# Simplest way to read a StorageFile end-to-end into a string?

Tags: javascript, c#, file, windows-10-universal, storagefile

I have a `StorageFile` object I'm trying to read into a string (for debugging purposes). What's the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#:

```
string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
```

In JavaScript:

```
var text = Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(storageFile).then(file => do_stuff(file))
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12804764)

Comment: I don't understand, there is no link in my answer?

Comment: Please explain above answer. rather than just typing the code.